# If $\Re e\langle Ax,y\rangle \leq M$, why $|\langle Ax,y\rangle| \leq M$?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$.

> Assume that $\Re e\langle Ax,y\rangle \leq M$ for all $x,y\in E$ and some constant $M$. Why
>   $$|\langle Ax,y\rangle| \leq M,\;\forall x,y\in E.$$

Comment: *Hint.* You may replace $y$ by $e^{i\theta}y$ and play with $\theta$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you but unfortunately I don't understand your idea

Comment: Let me begin with a simpler version: if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\operatorname{Re}(e^{i\theta}z) \leq M$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, then you can pick $\theta$ so that $e^{i\theta}z = |z|$ and hence $|z| \leq M$. Now you may apply the same idea to $z = \langle Ax, y \rangle$.

Comment: I prefer for the real part either $\Re z$ or $\mathrm{Re}\;z$.  Not a combination of fonts.

Comment: @SangchulLee I hope that you write your comment as an answer in order to accept it and thank you

Comment: I am glad that it helped, and sorry for being lazy to write an answer. Thankfully josephz took this task and wrote down one so you may accept his/her answer. :)

Comment: If $|\langle Ax,y\rangle| \leq M,\;\forall x,y\in E,\;$ then what about $|\langle Ax,ny\rangle|$ and $n$ integer? I think it would be unbounded.

Comment: @Somos: Or you just have $A = 0$     ;)

Comment: @genw: Right. So the hypothesis implies that $A=0$ and many results follow for the zero map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of Sangchul Lee's hint, you can perform a proof like this:

Consider the polar decomposition $\langle Ax,y\rangle=re^{i\theta}$ and then you'll have
$$
\mathfrak Re\langle Ax,e^{i\theta}y\rangle=r=|\langle Ax,y\rangle|.
$$
Thus $|\langle Ax,y\rangle|\leqslant M$.